# Return lines from a table where a value in one column is larger than the next but the corresponding value in a adjacent column is smaller

Tags: sql

I have this data:

[image]

It's ordered ascendingly by the left hand column.  I'd like a query that says if the timestamp in the right-hand column is before the timestamp of the preceding row, to return that row.

TIA

Comment: Sigh. Surely you can think of a better way than an image to put the sample data into the question? Maybe something that includes column names?

Comment: Also: with regards to databases -- and this is important -- there is no such thing as table order. If the order matters to your query, you **must** be able to specify this via code.

Comment: Finally, which database and version are you using? Because the best option here will absolutely change depending on whether you're using, say, MySql 5.7 vs MySql 8.0 or Sql Server 2008 R2 vs 2012 and later.

Comment: Lookup the LEAD() or LAG() analytical functions; provided your RDBMS supports them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.